# Protecting Github branches from Admins

Tags: github

I am asking this here because the Github docs do not have the answer, and I cannot find another answer anywhere else.

**I want to stop people from pushing to my master or development branches on github.**
Github appears to have this option but it doesn't work.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Go to the github repo settings page
2. Select 'Branch Protection Rules'
3. Enter the branch name I wish to protect
4. Click 'include administrators' - everyone on the repo is an admin
5. Click 'restrict who can push to matching branches'
6. Leave the 'restrict who...' empty, indicating that nobody can be
   exempt from the rule
7. Click Save.
8. Go to the protected branch on my local repo, make a change, commit and 
   push to the remote protected branch

**The result:** the change has been pushed to my protected branch.
**Expected result:** the change should be rejected from pushing to my protected branch

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior.  Maybe this is a new bug?

We ended up create a pre-commit hook and essentially enforcing it ourselves.

The only way I could force my admin account to make a PR using this interface was to require at least one review from another user.  Unfortunately that's too risky for us.

Comment: Hi Nathen, I can't remember the exact situation off the top of my head now, but I couldn't find a way around it - I had also resorted to creating a pre-commit hook.
Not entriely ideal, but suits our need just enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option.

> **Require review from Code Owners**
>
> Require an approved review in pull requests including files with a designated code owner.

You can find the option when you checking this.

> Require pull request reviews before merging

[image]